# AJAX Post request without form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a like system, but not using buttons or inputs i am using a href.

Ive tried a couple of different variations but my post requests arent getting sent?

My HTML code is:

```
<a href="#" id="likebutton"><i class="link-icon" data-feather="thumbs-up"></i></a><?php echo $likes;?>
```

My JS code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var like = "<?php echo $directory ?>";
$.ajax({
            url: 'gallery.php',
            data: { like : like },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function(data) {
                handleRequestError(data);
            }
        })
        </script>
```

And my php function:

```
if(isset($_POST['like']))
{
    $userid = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $likeid = $_POST['like'];
    $addlike = $users->add_like($userid, $of);
    if($addlike == 'success')
    {
    $message->display_success();
    }elseif($addlike == 'double'){
    $message->display_error();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure it out, I am very novice in using jQuery and AJAX and would appreciate some help in the right direction, thanks for your time.

Comment: You've got to create a `click` listener and put the ajax call inside that click listener.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, I am a novice at jQuery and AJAX, how do i do this? i've googled some but cant find a solid straight answer. @Leroy

Comment: Here’s a great tutorial for both jQuery and vanilla JS: https://gomakethings.com/listening-for-click-events-with-vanilla-javascript/